# Ant file copy pattern to match android lint output?

Tags: android, bamboo, lint

I am attempting to add android lint output as an artifact to my bamboo plan.

The lint output includes, at the same directory level, a file called "lint-results.html" and a directory called "lint-results_files" which contains some css and pngs to properly format the html file.  The root directory also contains some other files and folders I don't want included in the artifact.  What ant-style file copy pattern can I use to bring the html file and the supporting directory into a bamboo artifact?

Or - maybe simpler - is there a way I can control where the lint output appears, so I can just use **/* from a directory which has no extraneous files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set path to the lint's html-report with next lint options:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        htmlOutput file("build/lint/lint-report.html")
    }
}
```

Then use "**/* " mask for saving all produced output and set artifact location to "app/build/lint".